# Discriminant of algebraic number field is $0$ or $1 \bmod 4$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

I am reading the following theorem of  Ludwig Stickelberger in *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory* written by  S. Alaca and Kenneth S. Williams

> Let $K$ be an algebraic number field of degree $n$. Then the discriminant $d(K)$ of $K$ satisfies $d(K) \equiv 0 \text{ or } 1 \bmod 4$

To show this,
Let $\{w_1,w_2, \ldots,w_n \} $ be an integral basis for $K$. Let $\{w_i^{(j)} \, \vert \, j = 1,2 , \ldots n \}$ be the set of $K$ - conjugates of $w_i$ with $w_i^{(1)} = w_i$ for $i = 1,2 , \ldots ,n$ .

A fairly simple induction proof is sufficient to show that the expansion of determinant of $\det =
\begin{vmatrix} 
  w_1^{(1)} && w_2^{(1)} && \cdots && w_n ^{(1)} \\
  \vdots && \cdots && \cdots &&\vdots\\
  w_n^{(1)} && w_2^{(n)} && \cdots && w_n^{(n)}
\end{vmatrix}$

contains $n!$ terms, half of which occur with positive signs and half with negative
signs.

Let the sum of those with positive signs be $\lambda$ and those with negative signs $\mu$ so that
$$ \det = \lambda - \mu$$

Let $A = \lambda + \mu$ and $B= \lambda \mu$, then $d(K)= \det^2 = (\lambda - \mu)^2 = A^2 - 4B$

It is easy to see that $w_i^{(j)}$ is an algebraic integer and so does $\lambda$ and $\mu$ since the set of algebraic integers ($\Omega$) form integral domain. For the same reason, we see that $A, B \in \Omega$.

Now the aim is to show that $A$ and $B$ are rational numbers. We note that there exist $\theta \in \Omega$ such that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ and let $\theta_1 = \theta, \theta_2, \ldots ,\theta_n$ be conjugates of $\theta$ over rational numbers.
Then the author says

> If we express each $w_j$ as a polynomial in $\theta$ with rational coefficients, $A$
> becomes a symmetric function of $\theta_1, \cdots , \theta_n$ with rational coefficients and so $A \in \mathbb{Q}$

I know the author is using the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials to conclude that $A$ is a rational number. But I have issues with the above claim.

$1$. I think it should be

> $\dots w_j$ as a polynomial in $\theta_j$ with rational coefficients $\dots$

$2$. I do not understand how $A$ is a symmetric function in terms of $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n$. Of course, it is a function of $\theta_i$s but how we can conclude that it is a symmetric function? When I investigate the cases $n=2,3$ it is apparent. But it is becoming tedious to do for higher values of $n$.

What is the missing piece of the puzzle?

Comment: $A=\lambda+\mu$ is a sum over all permutations (c.f. the definition of determinant), so it is invariant under all permutations (i.e. symmetric). For $B$: any even permutation preserves both $\lambda$ and $\mu$, while any odd permutation exchanges to them, so $B$ is invariant. (A little remark: you can either use symmetric polynomials as you write, or a bit of Galois theory.)

Comment: +1 for adding all that context.

Comment: If $w_i=w_i^{(1)}$ is a polynomial say $f_i(\theta) $ in $\theta=\theta_1$ then $w_i^{(j)}$ is the same polynomial in $\theta_j$ ie $f_i(\theta_j) $. A typical term in determinant expansion is $(\text{sgn } \tau) \prod_{i=1}^n w_i^{(\tau(i))} =(\text{sgn }\tau) \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(\theta_{\tau(i)}) $ where $\tau$ is a permutation in $S_n$.

Comment: This does not answer your question but for a slightly different approach to the theorem, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394785/proof-of-stickelberger-s-theorem/1308240#1308240.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You are correct!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking hints from above comments, using the definition of determinant given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n_%C3%97_n_matrices), we see that
$$\det = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n w_{\sigma(i)}^{(i)} = \sum_{\sigma \in A_n}  \prod_{i=1}^n w_{\sigma(i)}^{(i)} - \sum_{\sigma \not \in A_n} \prod_{i=1}^n w_{\sigma(i)}^{(i)}  $$

So we take $\lambda = \sum_{\sigma \in A_n}  \prod_{i=1}^n w_{\sigma(i)}^{(i)} $ and $\mu = \sum_{\sigma \not \in A_n} \prod_{i=1}^n w_{\sigma(i)}^{(i)} $

Let $w_i = f_i(\theta)$ where $f_i$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients then $w_{\sigma(i)}^{(i)} = f_{\sigma(i)}(\theta^{(i)}) = f_{\sigma(i)}(\theta_{i})$. So

$$\lambda(\theta_1,\ldots\theta_n ) = \sum_{\sigma \in A_n}  \prod_{i=1}^n f_{\sigma(i)}(\theta_{i}) $$ and
$$\mu(\theta_1,\ldots\theta_n ) = \sum_{\sigma \not \in A_n} \prod_{i=1}^n f_{\sigma(i)}(\theta_{i}) $$

Let $\alpha \in A_n$, then
$$ \lambda(\theta_{\alpha(1)},\ldots,\theta_{\alpha(n)}) =\sum_{\sigma \in A_n}  \prod_{i=1}^n f_{\sigma(\alpha(i))}(\theta_{\alpha(i)}) = \sum_{\sigma 
 \circ \alpha \in A_n}  \prod_{i=1}^n f_{\sigma(\alpha(i))}(\theta_{\alpha(i)}) = \lambda $$
and similarly
$$ \mu(\theta_{\alpha(1)},\ldots,\theta_{\alpha(n)}) =\sum_{\sigma \not\in A_n}  \prod_{i=1}^n f_{\sigma(\alpha(i))}(\theta_{\alpha(i)}) = \sum_{\sigma 
 \circ \alpha \not \in A_n}  \prod_{i=1}^n f_{\sigma(\alpha(i))}(\theta_{\alpha(i)}) = \mu$$

So it shows that $\lambda $ and $\mu$ is invariant under even permutations.

In a similar manner it is easy to see that for any $\alpha \not\in A_n$,
$$\lambda(\theta_{\alpha(1)},\ldots,\theta_{\alpha(n)}) = \mu$$ and $$\mu(\theta_{\alpha(1)},\ldots,\theta_{\alpha(n)}) = \lambda$$

So $A= A(\theta_1, \ldots , \theta_n) =  \lambda + \mu  $ is invariant under both odd and even permutations hence symmetric polynomial in terms of $\theta_i$. So using fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials we can say that $A\in \mathbb{Q}$ as values of elementary symmetric polynomials are rational numbers. Also $B = \frac14(A^2 - d(K)) \in \mathbb{Q}$.

To finish the proof we see that $A, B\in \Omega$ so that $A , B\in \mathbb{Z}$
which shows that $d(K) \equiv 0 , 1 \mod4$.

This answers my both questions,

1. We can express $w_j$ in terms of $\theta$ and finish the proof.
2. $A$ is a symmetric polynomial in terms of $\theta_i.$